# C# + HTML UL, order list alphabetically "downwards"

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a list of strings already sorted alphabetically. However I want to display the alphabetical list on a web page "downwards".

ie: List is "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" and the number of columns is 4

At the moment my HTML page is displayed like so:

```
1     2     3     4
5     6     7
```

I want it to be displayed like this instead

```
1     3     5     7
2     4     6
```

I am using Razor to loop through the list and build an unordered list.

Does anyone have tips or algorithms to sort in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do the following:

```
int nrows = list.Count / nCols;

for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
    {
        // display item[(i * nCols) + j] in column j
    }
}
```

I don't know whether there's something automatic in the libraries that will do that for you.